# How to determine the "(default)" value of a key

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I want to know how can I get the default value of a registry key using C++.
I already tried sending `NULL` or an empty string in the key param in `RegQueryValueEx()` function.

Tried to check another key and I get it right. I just can't get the default.
The function returns `""` instead of the value.

Comment: Post your code using NULL or "" - this is how you do it per MSDN.  Perhaps the code has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "key param?" You should be passing `NULL` or `""` as the [`lpValueName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) parameter. If that's not working for you then it's a bug in your code. Post your code and perhaps we can provide further assistance.

Comment: I tried sending NULL or "" to lpValueName parameter. And this didnt work. when I tried getting another value other then (default) I succeeded.

Comment: [code]'void getVersion(char* o_version)
{
    const int MAX_VER = 40;
    HKEY hKey; 
    DWORD dwSize;
 DWORD dwType;
    wchar_t version[MAX_VER] = { 0 };

    if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, REG_KEY, 0 ,KEY_READ, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {        
        dwSize = MAX_VER;
        RegQueryValueEx(hKey, NULL, NULL, &dwType, (LPBYTE)&version, &dwSize); //(default)        
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }

    size_t converted = 0;
 char nstring[50];
 wcstombs_s(&converted, nstring,version, 50);
 
 strcpy(o_version, nstring);
}' when I trying other value it works